# redirect to a clients-side html-file in controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Is there a possibility to redirect the browser to a htm file on the client machine by using cakePhps contoller-function?

This is basically what I would like to achieve:

**Controller Method**:

```
function test(){
  if(someCondition){
    $this->redirect('C:\example\file.htm');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect only to files, that accessible on your server. But, you can use something like that:

```
$file = file_get_contents('C:\example\file.htm');
echo $file;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.
You have to use the file uri sheme:

`$this->redirect('file:///C:\example\file.htm');`